# How to display form details after validating a form correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that if I perform validation for the form alone, it performs correctly. But if I write a display function for displaying the details it can't perform the validation. How to do my validation for displaying the details which have been given to the form?

Is what I am giving on submit button correct? Are there any changes? How to declare both functions to perform correctly?

Then I have to do validation when I am displaying details. Please do help me to configure that.

```html
<form name="RegForm" action="/submit.php" method="post">  
    <p>Name: <input id="name" type="text" size=65 name="Name"> </p><br>     
    <p>Dob:  <input id="dob" type="date"></p><br>  
    <p> Address: <input id="address" type="text" size=65 name="Address">  </p><br> 
    <p>E-mail Address: <input id="mail" type="text" size=65 name="EMail">  </p><br> 
    <p>Password: <input id="pass" type="text" size=65 name="Password"> </p><br> 
    <p>Telephone: <input id="phone" type="text" size=65 name="Telephone"> </p><br>   
    <p>Comments:  <textarea cols="55" id="Comment" name="Comment">  </textarea></p> 
    <p><input type="submit" value="send" name="Submit" onclick="Validate(); results(); return false"> 
</form>
```

```html
function Validate()                                    
{ 
    var name = document.forms["RegForm"]["Name"];               
    var email = document.forms["RegForm"]["EMail"];    
    var phone = document.forms["RegForm"]["Telephone"];  
    var what =  document.forms["RegForm"]["Subject"];  
    var password = document.forms["RegForm"]["Password"];  
    var address = document.forms["RegForm"]["Address"];  
   
    if (name.value == "")                                  
    { 
        window.alert("Please enter your name."); 
        name.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   
    if (address.value == "")                               
    { 
        window.alert("Please enter your address."); 
        name.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
       
    if (email.value == "")                                   
    { 
        window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address."); 
        email.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   
    if (email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0)                 
    { 
        window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address."); 
        email.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   
    if (email.value.indexOf(".", 0) < 0)                 
    { 
        window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address."); 
        email.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   
    if (phone.value == "")                           
    { 
        window.alert("Please enter your telephone number."); 
        phone.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   
    if (password.value == "")                        
    { 
        window.alert("Please enter your password"); 
        password.focus(); 
        return flase; 
    } 
   
    if (what.selectedIndex < 1)                  
    { 
        alert("Please enter your course."); 
        what.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   }
  function results()
    { 
        
    var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
        
        var dob=document.getElementById('dob').value;
        
        var address=document.getElementById('address').value;
     
         var email=document.getElementById('mail').value;
    
         var phone=document.getElementById('phone').value;

              document.write("<b>Submitted Successfully!!</b>");
              document.write("<b>here is your data.</b><br/>");
      
    
        document.write("Name :"+name+ " <br/>");
    
       
       
        document.write("DateOfBirth :"+dob+ " <br/>");
    


    
        document.write("Address:"+address+ " <br/>");

     
      document.write("Email :"+email+ " <br/>");


        document.write("Telephone: "+phone+ " <br/>");

    }



</script>
```

How to configure this?

Comment: Do you have done any validations?

Comment: show your Validate()

Comment: onclick will execute both functions. validate then result.
So result should be called within validation or validation flag should be passed to result function.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your Javascript code is missing.